# How to update post in Django with out using Django forms

Tags: python, django

I want to update a post in Django, but I don't want to use Django forms for this is there any way to do that. Eg I want to update the title and description of my post.

Comment: then u have to create your on custom form and tell me what you want to update like 
Post something related to add some more detail brother

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax/Js to send post requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
def your_view_name(request, id):
     updata_data = modelname.objects.filter(id = id)
```

and then render out related fields in your template file